# Select rows such that specific column contains values from a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to obtain rows from numpy array that has specific value in one column. Example below shows my approach. I was able to get row when I gave specific value, but when I gave multiple values as `('4', '8')` I did not receive expected rows.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
arr2 = arr[arr[:,3] == 4]
arr3 = arr[arr[:,3] in ('4', '8')]
```

arr is `array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4],[ 5, 6, 7, 8], [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])`

arr2 is `array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])`

arr3 is `array([1, 2, 3, 4])`.

What command should I use to get output 
`array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create a mask of any occurrence of the elements that we are searching for and then simply use [`boolean indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select the valid rows off input array -

```
arr[np.in1d(arr[:,3], [4,8])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [149]: arr
Out[149]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [150]: np.in1d(arr[:,3], [4,8]) # Mask of valid ones
Out[150]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [151]: arr[np.in1d(arr[:,3], [4,8])] # Select rows off arr
Out[151]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I will accept this answer as soon as it is enabled (~10 min)

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no reason to deviate from the `numpy`-verse, I thought I'd provide another approach using a list comprehension:

```
idxs = [True if any(value in (4, 8) for value in row) else False for row in arr]

# convert it to a numpy array
idxs = np.array(idxs)

new_arr = arr[idxs]
```

See the results:

```
print(new_arr)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```